# Is it possible to compile golang code with dependencies?

Tags: go, compilation

Is it possible to compile golang code with dependencies? For an executable file was small.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in "[Linking golang statically](http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/)" ([Vincent Batts](http://www.slackware.com/~vbatts/)):

> As long as the source being compiled is native go, the go compiler will statically link the executable.
>   Though when you need to use cgo, then the compiler has to use its external linker.

A pure go program will show like this:

```
$> go build ./code-pure.go
$> ldd ./code-pure
        not a dynamic executable
$> file ./code-pure
./code-pure: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

This isn't so with cgo, unless you add an extra flag like:

```
go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-static"' ./code-cgo.go
# or, with gccgo
go build -compiler gccgo --gccgoflags "-static" ./code-cgo.go
```

Reminder, even with Go 1.5 (which uses go for compilation, and not `gc`), [gccgo will still be there](https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#2).